# Use CONCAT inside CONCAT in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a stored procedure and a part of it is:

```
SET @TableAlias = " ls_flock AS _flk ";
SET @Select = CONCAT(
    " _flk.Id as Id, _flk.Code as Code, ",
    CONCAT(" _em.FirstName", " ", "_em.LastName "), -- here I want to CONCAT 2 columns as one field.
    " as FlockManager"
  );
SET @Join = " JOIN employee as _em ON _flk.EmployeeId = _em.Id ";
```

I am unable to CONCAT two columns as a field with a `CONCAT` function.

And if I remove following line, code works fine:

```
CONCAT(" _em.FirstName", " ", "_em.LastName "), -- here I want to CONCAT 2 columns as one field.
    " as FlockManager"
```

I'm getting this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.LastName  as FlockManager FROM  ls_flock AS _flk  JOIN employee as _em ON _flk.' at line 1

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results =, and an explanation of the logic you want to imlement.

Comment: I have a state forward logic. I want to use CONCAT inside CONCAT.

Comment: Are you getting an error of some kind?

Comment: @kristech yeah, updated.

Comment: Are you using `prepared statements` inside your `stored procedure` to build the query you want?

Comment: @PeterDarmis No! I am using a NodeJs Framework Loopback 4, I am running the query from `this.dataSource.execute(sql)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that you want to generate a query string that uses `CONCAT()` - because I see that the table alias `_em` is declared further in the `@Join` variable. For this, you would need to move the function *inside* the query string.

```
SET @Select = CONCAT(
    " _flk.Id as Id, ",
    "_flk.Code as Code, ",
    "CONCAT(_em.FirstName, "" "", _em.LastName) s FlockManager"
;
```

And then, you just don't need the outer `CONCAT()`:

```
SET @Select = 
    " _flk.Id as Id, _flk.Code as Code, CONCAT(_em.FirstName, "" "", _em.LastName) as FlockManager";
```